# HTML DOCTYPE Syntax error

Tags: html

I get the following syntax error in Firebug and I don't get what's it:

```
> syntax error [Break on this error]
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTDXHT...org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">\n
```

Is it because of the final "\n" at the end ?

thanks

ps. I've just realized if I remove all scripts, I don't get that error. For example, if I remove these lines, I don't get it. If I add another script I get it again, so it doesn't depend on the script itself.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>sites/all/themes/bluemarine/js/main.js"></script>
```

CODE:

```
<?php
// $Id: page.tpl.php,v 1.28.2.1 2009/04/30 00:13:31 goba Exp $
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="<?php print $language->language ?>" xml:lang="<?php print $language->language ?>" dir="<?php print $language->dir ?>">
<head>
  <?php print $head ?>
  <title><?php print $head_title ?></title>
  <?php print $styles ?>
  <?php print $scripts ?>
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>sites/all/themes/bluemarine/js/main.js"></script>
  <!--<script type="text/JavaScript" src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>sites/all/themes/bluemarine/js/griddy-min.js"></script>
-->

</head>

<body>...
```

Comment: Source code of the HTML file?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Ryan Rampersad](http://blog.ryanrampersad.com/2008/09/syntax-error-break-on-this-error-doctype-html-public-w3cdtd-xhtml3orgtr-xhtml1-dtd-xhtml1-strictdtd/), blogged about this issue stating

> The error comes from Firebug. The break on this error isn’t a part of the error but it is in the firebug copy dump....

`syntax error [Break on this error] <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML…3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

> The way I encountered this error was that I forgot to specify a src attribute value for my script tag!

`<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>`

Here is the [blog post](http://blog.ryanrampersad.com/2008/09/syntax-error-break-on-this-error-doctype-html-public-w3cdtd-xhtml3orgtr-xhtml1-dtd-xhtml1-strictdtd/).

Comment: Thanks! The point is that all my scripts have "src". I mean, if I remove the last 2 lines (<script>) in the <head> then I don't get the issue. But they both have already src attriute

Comment: Yes but are they real javascript? What is the `Content-Type` returned by the server?

Comment: oh you're right! one of them is considered html.. what am I doing wrong then ? The content of the first script (for example, is just a jquery function).. I don't think it is formatted badly

Comment: uhm, how can I change it ? I'm actually storing it on my localhost and my local apache always worked correctly so far. Also, on another website on the same localkhost I don't have issues

Comment: Here's the new link to the above blog post - http://blog.ryanrampersad.com/2008/09/syntax-error-break-on-this-error-doctype-html-public-w3cdtd-xhtml3orgtr-xhtml1-dtd-xhtml1-strictdtd/

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Please update your post with the new link... gotta love link only answers eh.

Comment: To throw the `src=""` that caused the error, it looks like `<?php echo $base_url; ?sites/all/themes/bluemarine/js/main.js` must have been coming back as empty.  So while this answer says this is what caused the error, the OP would still have to figure out why it was empty.

Comment: mine was not putting the type attribute on some script tags `type="text/javascript"`

Answer (score 15):

I suspect that you have a `<script>` pointing to a URL that returns an HTML document (possibly it should be coming with a 404 response but isn't)

Comment: well, you see in the code they point to a js file. And in Firebug it is found (not 404 error is returned)

Comment: Putting `.js` on the end of a URL doesn't make it a JS file. Servers (with some very rare exceptions) send HTML documents as the body of 404 errors. Sometimes they are misconfigured so they 404 error body comes with a 200 status code.

Comment: what makes a js file then ? I just have javascript in it. thanks

Comment: I had this problem, because the server returned a login page instead of the JavaScript file.

Comment: There was some advertiser JS file added to the footer of my page that was causing this error, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. For me the problem was that I loaded a script file that pointed to nowhere or to be more precise it pointed to my domain root. The script declaration was `<script src="http://mydomain/" type="text/javascript" />`. What was happening was that the script was loading my home page. The first character of a home page is "<" because all html pages start with `"<!DOCTYPE ......"`. Well this is a syntax error so and that was it. Once I eliminated `<script src="http://mydomain/" type="text/javascript" />` everything was ok. I hope I helped you.
**EDIT:** In short, check your `src` pointers on your Javascript links to be sure they point at the correct files.

Comment: I was working on this issue from a long time. Thank you!

You saved my job :-)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, when I received such error, the cause was "un authorised access" to the JS file.

To detect it, use FireBug, [HTML] tab: Try to expand each "script" node.
one of these nodes contained the "401.html" page-content instead of the expected JS content.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After trying many solution and searching about it, finally I got why I was getting that error.

I was getting that error because of invalid path in src attribute of script tag.
Like I was adding script as below by simply dragging script on page from solution explorer in visual studio and I was getting error.
My src attribute in script tag was **src="~/js/jquery.min.js"**

And I found that I was not getting script on that page.

So I used below solution to load script on that page.
src attribute in script tag **src="../../js/jquery.min.js"**